# Specification pattern in EF part 1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I've been experimenting with different ways of reusing (and naming) the expressions I use in Entity Framework. I've tried static fields with `Expression`s and extension methods but neither are perfect. In my latest attempt to solve this problem, I'm attempting to implement the specification pattern!

Firstly, I created a hierarchy for Specifications:

## Specification.cs

```
public abstract class Specification<T>
{
    public abstract Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression();

    public abstract bool IsSatisfiedBy(T target);

    public static implicit operator Expression<Func<T, bool>>(Specification<T> specification)
    {
        if (specification == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(specification));
        }
        return specification.ToExpression();
    }

    public Specification<T> And(Specification<T> other)
    {
        ValidateForCompose(other);
        return new AndSpecification<T>(this, other);
    }

    public Specification<T> Or(Specification<T> other)
    {
        ValidateForCompose(other);
        return new OrSpecification<T>(this, other);
    }

    public Specification<T> Negate()
    {
        return new NotSpecification<T>(this);
    }

    public static Specification<T> operator ! (Specification<T> specification)
    {
        if (specification == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(specification));
        }
        return specification.Negate();
    }

    private void ValidateForCompose(Specification<T> other)
    {
        if (ToExpression() == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Cannot compose an empty specification with another specification.");
        }
        if (other == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(other));
        }
    }
}
```

## NotSpecification

```
public class NotSpecification<T> : Specification<T>
{
    private readonly Specification<T> specification;

    public NotSpecification(Specification<T> specification)
    {
        if (specification == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(specification));
        }
        this.specification = specification;
    }

    public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        return specification.ToExpression().Negate();
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T target)
    {
        return !specification.IsSatisfiedBy(target);
    }
}
```

## CompositeSpecification

```
public abstract class CompositeSpecification<T> : Specification<T>
{
    protected readonly Specification<T>[] Specifications;

    protected CompositeSpecification(params Specification<T>[] specifications)
    {
        if (specifications == null || !specifications.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(specifications));
        }
        Specifications = specifications;
    }
}
```

## AndSpecification

```
 public class AndSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    public AndSpecification(params Specification<T>[] specifications)
        : base(specifications)
    {
    }

    public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        var firstSpecification = Specifications.First().ToExpression();
        if (Specifications.Length == 1)
        {
            return firstSpecification;
        }
        return Specifications.Skip(1)
            .Aggregate(firstSpecification, 
                (current, specification) => current.And(specification.ToExpression()));
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T target)
    {
        return Specifications.All(s => s.IsSatisfiedBy(target));
    }
}
```

## OrSpecification

```
public class OrSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    public OrSpecification(params Specification<T>[] specifications)
        : base(specifications)
    {
    }

    public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        var firstSpecification = Specifications.First().ToExpression();
        if (Specifications.Length == 1)
        {
            return firstSpecification;
        }
        return Specifications.Skip(1)
            .Aggregate(firstSpecification, (current, specification) => current.Or(specification.ToExpression()));
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T target)
    {
        return Specifications.Any(s => s.IsSatisfiedBy(target));
    }
}
```

## ExpressionSpecification

```
public abstract class ExpressionSpecification<T> : Specification<T>
{
    protected abstract Expression<Func<T, bool>> Expression { get; }

    public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        return Expression;
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T target)
    {
        return Expression.Compile()(target);
    }
}
```

There are a couple of Extension methods which make composing the Expressions possible:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(second, first.Parameters);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(first.Body, invokedExpr), first.Parameters).ExpandInvocations();
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(second, first.Parameters);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(first.Body, invokedExpr), first.Parameters).ExpandInvocations();
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Negate<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(expr.Body), expr.Parameters).ExpandInvocations();
    }

    private static Expression<T> ExpandInvocations<T>(this Expression<T> expr)
    {
        return expr.VisitWith(new InvocationExpander());
    }

    public static Expression<T> VisitWith<T>(this Expression<T> expression, params ExpressionVisitor[] visitors)
    {
        return (Expression<T>)((Expression)expression).VisitWith(visitors);
    }

    public static Expression VisitWith(this Expression expression, params ExpressionVisitor[] visitors)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        }
        return visitors == null
            ? expression 
            : visitors.Aggregate(expression, (current, visitor) => visitor.Visit(current));
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
// Taken/modified from:
// https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/meek/2008/12/07/invocationexpression-and-linq-to-entities/
public class InvocationExpander : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _parameter;
    private readonly Expression _expansion;
    private readonly InvocationExpander _previous;

    public InvocationExpander() { }

    private InvocationExpander(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression expansion, InvocationExpander previous)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
        _expansion = expansion;
        _previous = previous;
    }

    public InvocationExpander Push(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression expansion)
    {
        return new InvocationExpander(parameter, expansion, this);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression iv)
    {
        if (iv.Expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Lambda)
        {
            return base.VisitInvocation(iv);
        }
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)iv.Expression;
        return lambda
            .Parameters
            .Select((x, i) => new { Parameter = x, Expansion = iv.Arguments[i] })
            .Aggregate(this, (previous, pair) => previous.Push(pair.Parameter, pair.Expansion))
            .Visit(lambda.Body);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p)
    {
        var expander = this;
        while (null != expander)
        {
            if (expander._parameter == p)
            {
                return base.Visit(expander._expansion);
            }
            expander = expander._previous;
        }
        return base.VisitParameter(p);
    }

}
```

All of that allows me to do something like:

```
public class IsPublic : ExpressionSpecification<Posting>
{
    private static readonly Expression<Func<Posting, bool>> IsPublicExpression =
        p => p.VisibilityId == PostingVisibilityId.Public;

    protected override Expression<Func<Posting, bool>> Expression => IsPublicExpression;
}
```

The real expressiveness comes from being able to make lots of small Specifications which are then either composed using `And` or `Or` or by creating reusable `CompositeExpression`s:

```
public class IsAnIncompleteChange : AndSpecification<Response>
{
    public IsAnIncompleteChange()
        : base(
            new IsPublic(),
            new LinkedPostingIsPublic(),
            new IsFromASubscription(),
            new IsPlanningChange(),
            new SubsequentChangeHasNotBeenMade())
    {
    }
}
```

Both of those are examples from the real application that I'm trying this out on. So why am I trying to do this?

Up until now we've had extension methods for reusable predicates which looks nice but I found that the generated SQL (when things get complex with projections and joins) sometimes repeats predicates in sub queries when we were doing things like:

```
// postings is an IQueryable
postings.WhichArePublic()
        .WhichAreSignedPersonally()
        .WhichAreInResponseToACriticalPosting()
        .ProjectIntoFeaturedPostingModel();
```

By creating specifications instead I've been able to quite dramatically decrease the cost of several of our more expensive queries (up to 70% reduction in reads and elapsed time). Not to mention more readable queries:

```
postings.Where(new HasPublicPersonalResponseToCriticalPosting());
```

The limitation with the above is that you can't use them within an Expression e.g.

```
postings.Select(p => new { Responses = p.Responses.AsQueryable().Where(new IsPublic()) });
```

Which is where [part 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138283/specification-pattern-in-ef-part-2) comes in...

So, can this code be improved?

Is there a better way of reusing predicates and having modular and well named predicates?

Have I made any glaring coding (or style) mistakes?

Comment: The pattern might be called specification pattern but I'd name the classes operator. Specification sounds strange.

Comment: @t3chb0t - naming is *hard* ;) a dictionary definition of "Specification" is "a detailed description of the design and materials used to make something." which I think fits but I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: I know ;-) I often spend more time thinking of a good name then doing what needs to be done ;-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing something, but from what I can see `IsSatisfiedBy` is only ever used by `IsSatisfiedBy`, and can be removed.

Consider making `ToExpression` protected, since with the implicit operator I don't see how exposing it is helpful.

Consider exposing operators `&` and `|` to make composition of more complicated specifications easier to read and write.

Here's an illustration of how I'm imaginging it:

```
public abstract class Specification<T>
{
    protected abstract Expression<Func<T, bool>> Expression { get; }

    public static implicit operator Expression<Func<T, bool>>(Specification<T> specification)
    {
        if (specification == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(specification));
        }

        return specification.Expression;
    }

    public Specification<T> And(Specification<T> second)
    {
        if (second == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));
        }

        return new AndSpecification(this, second);
    }

    public static Specification<T> operator &(Specification<T> first, Specification<T> second)
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));
        }

        if (second == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));
        }

        return new AndSpecification(first, second);
    }

    private sealed class AndSpecification : Specification<T>
    {
        public AndSpecification(Specification<T> first, Specification<T> second)
        {
            Expression = first.Expression.And(second);
        }

        protected override Expression<Func<T, bool>> Expression { get; }
    }


    // Similarly for or, not.
}
```

And example client code

```
public class IsSomeExample : Specification<Posting>
{
    protected override Expression<Func<Posting, bool>> Expression =>
        new IsPrivate() | (new IsFromASubscription() & new LinkedPostingIsPublic());
}
```

Comment: Interesting comments - I'm never sure about overriding `|` and `&` because I always think about them in terms of bitwise operations but it does make composition nicer... `IsSatisfiedBy` is used in other parts of the app on in memory collections.

Answer (score 1):

**Concatenating expressions**

> ```
> public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression()
> {
>     var firstSpecification = Specifications.First().ToExpression();
>     if (Specifications.Length == 1)
>     {
>         return firstSpecification;
>     }
>     return Specifications.Skip(1)
>         .Aggregate(firstSpecification, 
>             (current, specification) => current.And(specification.ToExpression()));
> }
> ```

This isn't necessary. I think this should work too:

```
return 
    Specifications.Aggregate(
        Expression.Empty(), // or Expression.Constant(true)
        (current, specification) => current.And(specification.ToExpression()
    ));
```

Comment: The first iteration of code aggregated starting with a constant true expression but it means that the SQL ends up having tautologies in it (i.e. `1 = 1 AND ...`). That's not a disaster but I did want to avoid it. I probably need to comment that bit of code.