# Specification pattern in EF part 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

This is a follow on to [Part 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138282/specification-pattern-in-ef-part-1)

In order to use my new `Specification`s within expression trees so I can use them in projections/navigation collections I had to write an ExpressionVisitor to find `Specification`s and replace them with their `Expression`.

In order to convert an IQueryable into one that supports the specifications, I created an Extension Method called `AsSpecifiable()`:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> AsSpecifiable<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        var visitableQuery = query as VisitableQuery<T>;
        return visitableQuery ?? new VisitableQuery<T>(query, new SpecificationExpander());
    }
}
```

Which uses a `VisitableQuery`:

```
// Based on:
// http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx
// http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.html
public class VisitableQuery<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly VisitableQueryProvider<T> provider;

    internal IQueryable<T> InnerQuery { get; } 

    internal VisitableQuery(IQueryable<T> inner, params ExpressionVisitor[] visitors)
    {
        InnerQuery = inner;
        provider = new VisitableQueryProvider<T>(this, visitors);
    }

    Expression IQueryable.Expression => InnerQuery.Expression;

    Type IQueryable.ElementType => typeof(T);

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider => provider;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return InnerQuery.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return InnerQuery.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return InnerQuery.ToString();
    }
}
```

And the corresponding QueryProvider:

```
// Based on:
// http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx
// http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.html
public class VisitableQueryProvider<T> : IQueryProvider
{
    private readonly ExpressionVisitor[] interceptors;

    private readonly VisitableQuery<T> query;

    internal VisitableQueryProvider(
        VisitableQuery<T> query,
        ExpressionVisitor[] interceptors)
    {
        this.query = query;
        this.interceptors = interceptors;
    }

    IQueryable<TElement> IQueryProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return
            new VisitableQuery<TElement>(
                query.InnerQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<TElement>(
                    expression.VisitWith(interceptors)));
    }

    IQueryable IQueryProvider.CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return query.InnerQuery.Provider.CreateQuery(expression.VisitWith(interceptors));
    }

    TResult IQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return
            query.InnerQuery.Provider.Execute<TResult>(expression.VisitWith(interceptors));
    }

    object IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return query.InnerQuery.Provider.Execute(expression.VisitWith(interceptors));
    }
}
```

And finally the ExpressionVisitor:

```
public class SpecificationExpander : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
    {
        var declaringType = node.Method?.DeclaringType;
        if (declaringType != null
            && declaringType.IsGenericType
            && declaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Specification<>))
        {
            if (node.Method.Name == "op_Implicit")
            {
                var method = typeof(Specification<>).MakeGenericType(declaringType.GetGenericArguments()).GetMethod(nameof(Specification<object>.ToExpression));
                if (node.Operand.NodeType == ExpressionType.Not)
                {
                    var operand = ((UnaryExpression)node.Operand).Operand;
                    var expanded = ExpandConversion(Visit(operand), method);
                    if (expanded != null)
                    {
                        var negate = typeof(ExpressionExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(ExpressionExtensions.Negate)).MakeGenericMethod(declaringType.GetGenericArguments());
                        return (Expression)negate.Invoke(null, new object[] { expanded }); ;
                    }
                }
                else if (node.Operand.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
                {
                    var expression = Visit(node.Operand);
                    var expanded = ExpandConversion(expression, method);
                    if (expanded != null)
                    {
                        return expanded;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var expanded = ExpandConversion(node.Operand, method);
                    if (expanded != null)
                    {
                        return expanded;
                    }
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot convert the specification ({node.Type.Name}) to an expression");
                }
            }
        }
        return base.VisitUnary(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        var declaringType = node.Method.DeclaringType;
        if (declaringType != null
            && declaringType.IsGenericType
            && declaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Specification<>))
        {
            if (node.Method.Name == nameof(Specification<object>.ToExpression))
            {
                var expanded = ExpandConversion(Visit(node.Object), node.Method);
                if (expanded != null)
                {
                    return expanded;
                }
            }
            else if (node.Method.Name == nameof(Specification<object>.Negate))
            {
                var value = GetValue((MemberExpression)node.Object);
                var negate = typeof(Specification<>).MakeGenericType(declaringType.GetGenericArguments()).GetMethod(nameof(Specification<object>.Negate));
                var specification = negate.Invoke(value, null);
                return Expression.Constant(specification, specification.GetType());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"{node.Method.Name} cannot be used within an expression");
            }
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }

    private Expression ExpandConversion(Expression node, MethodInfo method)
    {
        var newExpression = node as NewExpression;
        if (newExpression != null)
        {
            var parameters = GetArgumentValues(newExpression.Arguments);
            var specification = newExpression.Constructor.Invoke(parameters);
            return (Expression)method.Invoke(specification, null);
        }
        var memberExpression = node as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            return (Expression)method.Invoke(GetValue(memberExpression), null);
        }
        var constantExpression = node as ConstantExpression;
        if (constantExpression != null)
        {
            return (Expression)method.Invoke(constantExpression.Value, null);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private object[] GetArgumentValues(IReadOnlyList<Expression> arguments)
    {
        if (arguments?.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var results = new object[arguments.Count];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.Count; i++)
        {
            var constant = arguments[i] as ConstantExpression;
            if (constant != null)
            {
                results[i] = constant.Value;
                continue;
            }

            var member = arguments[i] as MemberExpression;
            if (member != null)
            {
                results[i] = GetValue(member);
                continue;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid argument to specification constructor.");

        }
        return results;
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/2616980/1402923
    public static object GetValue(Expression expression)
    {
        var objectMember = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object));
        var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);
        return getterLambda.Compile().Invoke();
    }
}
```

This question relies on code which is present in part 1 so you'll need to grab all of the code there if you want to run it. That said, here's what it looks like when it's used:

```
var activeMemberAlertFinders = from s in subscriptions.AsSpecifiable()
                               from m in s.Members.AsQueryable().Where(new MemberIsActive())
                               from a in m.Alerts.AsQueryable().Where(new AlertIsActive())
                               select a.Scope;
```

All of this code works but I can't help but feel I massively over complicated the Visitor - I've never written one that does this sort of thing before.

How can I improve this code or should I just scrap it and go back to using static fields storing `Expression`s?

**Edit**

Just in case it makes life easier, I've put all of the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Rob89/Rh.Specifiable) minus the tests which I have yet to migrate away from Machine.Specifications.

Comment: I know the pain about the `Visitor`. I was also experimenting with it and there is as good as no documentation, examples or anything hepful other then the basic stuff.

Comment: @t3chb0t - yeah exactly. I thought I had a good grasp on expression trees before I started this. I now realise that they are much more complicated than I gave them credit for!

Comment: Would you let me know when you've migrated the tests please? I'd like to play around with it.

Comment: @t3chb0t - have my in-laws staying over the weekend so haven't been able to make much progress on it. I just sneaked off for a bit and did a couple (9) of the easy tests which should hopefully give you something to go on!

Comment: Thank you ;-) it's nothing urgent. I've updated my fork.

Comment: I thought I'll try again to crack how it works but I cannot figure out what the visitor is actually doing. Could you tell me in few words what expanding means in this context?

Comment: @t3chb0t - the visitor looks for nodes with a type of `Specification<>` (which EF can't translate to SQL) and replaces them with the result of calling `ToExpression` on that specification (which EF can translate). It seems to get horrid when you consider things like the spec coming from a closure vs `new Specification` in the expression.

Comment: The `InvocationExpander` is such a brain twister. All the invocations and parameters and the recursive pseudo-stack-something. It's horrible the way it is build and especially this ugly `while` search. This makes it even more crazy.

Comment: @t3chb0t - yeah I know what you mean... As linked, it's not code that I directly wrote. At one point I thought it behaving as a stack was elegant but I'm not so sure now.

Comment: I made this thing non-stack/recursive. What do you think of this [InvocationExpander](https://gist.github.com/he-dev/720fefc8f9d171bad5b1e415e343981e)? I tested it with a few queries and it woked so far.

Comment: Could you give me an example where the `SpecificationExpander` would kick in? I'm still in the process of learning the expressions and I cannot come up with a case by just looking at the code.

Comment: @t3chb0t - it will be used when you use a specification inside an expression. I put an example in the readme of the GitHub repo https://github.com/Rob89/Rh.Specifiable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the code it's ok. I wouldn't scrap it all and start again as the usage is clean and sensible.

The code is readable and as you've based this on a pattern should be maintainable.